# Difference b/w Method[Int]() vs Method() in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

After seeing the method signature of map in scala as

`def map[A, B](l: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = ???`

my layman undersanting of [A, B] in above is that they signal the method that we'll be exclusively working with generic Type A and B in the defined method.

Now I go on to implement a method to add values from two lists consquetively (basically zipWith) using similar coding pattern.

```
def addCorresponding[Int](l1: List[Int],
                        l2: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  (l1, l2) match {
      case (_, Nil) => Nil
      case (Nil, _) => Nil
      case (x::xs, y::ys) => {
          List((x + y)) ++ addCorresponding(xs, ys)
      }
}
```

but get this error while adding the elements in the last match:
[type mismatch found: Int Required: String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgmAl.png)

Removeing the [Int] from the mehtod sigature fixes this error.

I'm sure there are holes in my understanding of generic Types and when to add them to the method signature. I'd appreciate if someone can walk me through this and explain why the `addCorresponding` method with [Int] errors out but works fine without it?

Comment: A type parameter is basically that, a parameter. Is like when you do `def plusFive(x: Int): Int = x + 5`, what is `x`? Anything, whatever is passed to the function. It is not `1`, nor `0` nor even `5` or `3`, it is just a parameter. So in the first example `A` and `B` are parameters for types, meaning they are not any proper type right now, they will be filled by the compiler when called. In your second example you want both lists to be of type **Int** since you want to sum the elements, that is something you can only do with **Ints**, so not need to add a type parameter.

Comment: Also note that when you do `[Int] ` you are creating a type parameter named `Int` which shadows the type **Int**, that is why it doesn't work when you add that.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65322171/2359227

Comment: BTW, why aren't you using `zip`? It does exactly what you are trying to do. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yYCapPvmSgWWE467QRh4ZQ

Comment: @TomerShetah Thanks for sharing the links. I've just started learning Scala through the Red book and was stumped at implementing zip on my own as per one of the exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic method (taking a *type parameter*) would be

```
def addCorresponding[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A]): List[A]
```

or, if the lists can have different types of elements

```
def addCorresponding[A, B, C](l1: List[A], l2: List[B]): List[C]
```

If you implement a method that works on a *concrete type* `Int`, then your method is no longer generic:

```
def addCorresponding(l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]): List[Int]
```

In other words, you apply a concrete type `Int` here to `List[_]` instead of an abstract type parameter. If you write

```
def addCorresponding[Int](l1: List[Int], l2: List[Int]): List[Int]
```

then you **"shadow"** the concrete type `Int` with an abstract type parameter `Int` that happens to have the same name; but technically you are writing the generic method

```
def addCorresponding[XXX](l1: List[XXX], l2: List[XXX]): List[XXX]
```

If you want to keep your method generic but perform certain operations on elements of type `A`, you may need a type class, for example `Numeric` to arithmetically add elements

```scala
def addCorresponding[A](l1: List[A],
                        l2: List[A])(implicit num: Numeric[A]): List[A] =
  (l1, l2) match {
    case (_, Nil) => Nil
    case (Nil, _) => Nil
    case (x::xs, y::ys) =>
      List((num.plus(x, y))) ++ addCorresponding(xs, ys)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and a generic implementation.