# How to specify tuple type signature

Tags: scala, generics, tuples, type-parameter

I'm working through the "Learning Scala" book and have gotten to this exercise in chapter 4:

> Write a function that takes a 3-sized tuple and returns a 6-sized tuple, with each original parameter followed by its String representation.  For example, invoking the function with (true, 22.25, "yes") should return (true, "true", 22.5, "22.5", "yes", "yes").

The most promising of my attempts to specify the type signature is this:

`def t3ToT6[Tuple3[A, B, C]](t: Tuple3[A, B, C]) = {`

produces these errors:

```
Exercises.scala:99: error: not found: type A
  def t3ToT6[Tuple3[A, B, C]](t: Tuple3[A, B, C]) = {
                                        ^
Exercises.scala:99: error: not found: type B
  def t3ToT6[Tuple3[A, B, C]](t: Tuple3[A, B, C]) = {
                                           ^
Exercises.scala:99: error: not found: type C
  def t3ToT6[Tuple3[A, B, C]](t: Tuple3[A, B, C]) = {
                                              ^
```

The intent is to allow any type, so I though I could indicate those with the `A`, `B`, or `C`?

If I take away the type specification and just use `Tuple3`, then it complains that I *should* have type params:

```
Exercises.scala:99: error: type Tuple3 takes type parameters
  def t3ToT6[Tuple3[A, B, C]](t: Tuple3) = {
```

I suspect I'm close, and this is some sort of syntax issue, but have not yet found any examples of specifying Tuples in type signatures of functions.

What is the correct type signature for this problem description?

Are there examples you know of that I've not yet found which would help me understand this?

Comment: `def t3ToT6[Tuple3[A, B, C]](...)` would work if types `A`, `B`, `C` have already been defined. To specify type parameters for your method `t3ToT6`, it should be something like  `def t3ToT6[A, B, C](t: Tuple3[A, B, C]) = ???` or `def t3ToT6[A, B, C](t: (A, B, C)) = ???`.

Comment: The book probably already covered generics, it would be good to re-do that section since it seems you are still a little bit confused about those.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I don't see "generic" in the book anywhere, so if they cover what you are speaking of, it is by another name.  https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/ix01.html

Comment: @CraigTreptow then search for type parameters. Here is a good TL;DR; but it would good to read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65452344/difference-b-w-methodint-vs-method-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identify 3 type parameters like so: `[A,B,C]`

With this you can ...

```
def t3ToT6[A,B,C](t: Tuple3[A,B,C]):Tuple6[A,String,B,String,C,String] =
  Tuple6(t._1, t._1.toString
        ,t._2, t._2.toString
        ,t._3, t._3.toString)
```

It can also be done with a quick pattern match.

```
def t3ToT6[A,B,C](t:(A,B,C)):(A,String,B,String,C,String) = t match {
  case (a,b,c) => (a, a.toString, b, b.toString, c, c.toString)
}
```

Comment: So are the [] used *only* for specifying tuple type signatures?

Comment: No, they have nothing to do with tuples whatsoever.